# Reusing variant gives type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm dealing with the well-known problem of `INDEX()` returning 0 when the value is blank.

I use a `Variant` variable where I put the value, then I compare it to "" and replace with "" if it is equal to "" (Excel logic...). The problem is that it is a loop and reusing the same Variant variable every time doesn't work (after the first line it starts giving zeroes where it should give blanks, in the end it returns Type mismatch error).

I ended up using an array of variants so the variable is new for each loop step. It works but I suppose it's not effective, how can I improve it (reuse the variable `CurrCellValue`?)?

```
Dim CurrCellValue() As Variant
ReDim CurrCellValue(2 To LowerLastHistoryLine, 4 To 55) As Variant

For CurrLine = 2 To LowerLastHistoryLine
For CurrCol = 4 To 55
    On Error Resume Next
    CurrCellValue(CurrLine, CurrCol) = _
        WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("История_прогноз").Range("A1:" & Sheets("История_прогноз").Cells(LastDataLine, LastHistCol).Address(False, False)), _
        WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Seas_Lower").Cells(CurrLine, 3).Value, Sheets("История_прогноз").Range("A:A"), 0), _
        WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Seas_Lower").Cells(1, CurrCol).Value & "." & Sheets("Seas_Lower").Cells(CurrLine, 2).Value, _
            Sheets("История_прогноз").Range("1:1"), 0))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If CurrCellValue(CurrLine, CurrCol) = "" Then 'type mismatch here
        Sheets("Seas_Lower").Cells(CurrLine, CurrCol).Value = ""
    Else
        Sheets("Seas_Lower").Cells(CurrLine, CurrCol).Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(CurrCellValue(CurrLine, CurrCol), "")
    End If
Next CurrCol
Next CurrLine
```

Comment: What is the value of `CurrCellValue(CurrLine, CurrCol)` when it errors.  I will bet it is an error.  Test for the error first then replace it with `""`

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Index` doesn't return 0 for a blank cell. It returns a Range object and the value of that range is not 0.

Comment: @Rory but when it's value is applied to a cell it's zero.

Comment: No it isn't. If you apply `Empty`, which is what would be returned by an empty cell, to a cell you get an empty cell. Note: this is not the same as INDEX in a *formula*, which does return 0 for an empty cell.